# PHP, javascript, single quote problems with IE when passing variable from ajax post to javascript function

Tags: php, javascript, escaping

I have been trying to get this to work for a while, and I suspect there's an easy solution that I just can't find. My head feels like jelly and I would really appreciate any help.

My main page.php makes a .post() to backend.php and fetches a list of cities which it echoes in the form of:

```
<li onclick="script('$data');">$data</li>
```

The list is fetched and put onto the page via .html().

My problem occurs when $data has a single quote in it. backend.php passes the variable just fine to page.php but when i run html() it throws a javascript error (in IE, not FF obviously);

*')' is expected*

IE parses the single quote and messes up the script()-call. I've been trying to rebuild the echoed string in different ways, escaping the 's on the php side and/or on the javascript side - but in vain. Do I have to review the script in total?

page.php

```
$.post("backend.php", {q: ""+str+""}, function(data) {
    if(data.length >0) {
         $('#results').html(data);
    }
```

backend.php

```
while ($row = $q->fetch()) {
    $city = $row['City'];
//  $city = addslashes($row['City']);
//  $city = str_replace("'","&#39;",$row['City']);
    echo "<li onclick=\"script('$city');\">".$city."</li>";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two encodings: One for the JavaScript context and one for the HTML context:

- [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) is for encoding the data for JavaScript and
- [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) for the HTML part.

So try this:

```
echo '<li onclick="script(' . htmlspecialchars(json_encode($row['City'])) . ')">' . htmlspecialchars($row['City']) . '</li>';
```

Comment: You are a god given man to the lesser gifted :) Works perfectly, nice solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could call `script()` and then reference `this.innerhtml`.

```
<li onclick="script();">$data</li>
```

And then in your javascript:

```
function script() {
    data = this.innerHTML;
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: It’s `innerHTML` and not `innerhtml`.

Answer (score 1):

what about backslash escaping it?:

```
$city = str_replace("'","\'",$row['City']);
```

Comment: Tried it, don't think it worked, but I have flipped around with different settings so much I couldn't be sure :) Gumbos solution up there were nice though.

Answer (score 1):

To make your life easier, I would dispense with using `onclick` if you can and include scripts in the `<head>` of the page and register click handlers based on id/class.  And even better, use jQuery to do that, but you're probably aware of jQuery already if you've been around S.O. enough.

Single/Double/Triple escaping all the time just isn't worth it.

Comment: You are probably right about that, I am evolving the example I found. Will probably make it more intuitive in further developments.

Answer (score 1):

My contribution to proceedings, uses your existing function with minimal change.

```
<li onclick="script(this.innerHTML);">$data</li>
```